# How to remove the new line in redir command?

Tags: vimscript

I am using a command like this:

```
:redir @+ | set guifont | redir END
```

The output of the command above is:

```
  guifont=Source Code Pro:h14
```

Note the blank line at the beginning. How can I remove it? I tried the following:

```
:redir @+ | set guifont | redir END | %s/^\n//
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were on the right track trying to substitute the newline with nil, but `:%s` works on a buffer. What you needed to execute the substitution on is the content of the clipboard, which resides in the clipboard register (see `:h @r`).

The correct way to capture the clean output of a command then is this:

```
redir @+ | set guifont | redir END | let @+ = substitute(@+, '\n', '', '')
```

But this was the correct way of *your* approach. There are other, better ways. For example, instead of using the convoluted way of `:h redir`, we can directly capture the output of a command with `:h execute()` and put it in the clipboard register. Any leading and trailing newline and whitespace can be removed with `:h trim()`.

```
let @+ = trim(execute('set guifont'))
```

---

This answer deals with capturing the output of an ex-command, not taking into account what the command is. For the exact use case of this question, which is to capture the output of a set-option command, it's simpler to use [Christian Brabandt's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/38872/16280)

Answer (score 5):

For getting the value of options, vim provides a better way, see [:h expr-option](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-option)

So to get the option value of the 'guifont' setting, you can simply use:

```
:echo &guifont
```

You can put the value in the system clipboard with:

```
:let @+ = &guifont
```

Comment: Damn. I got so tunnel-visioned, I didn't even realize what it is OP was trying to do. LOL.